# sscanf() invalid operants

Tags: c, compiler-errors, scanf

So I am trying to run a sscanf on char *temp[512], but i get an error( error:invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'float').
char *temp[512] contains info:
**Flen 2014-5-20 19.90 14.15 19.91 2014-05-21 15.05 11.3 15.05**

```
char dates[13];
char dates2[13];
char city[15];
float temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6;
sscanf(temp,"%s %s %f %f %f %s %f %f %f",
            city, dates ,&temp1, &temp2, &temp3, dates2 &temp4, &temp5, &temp6);
```

Comment: `dates2 &temp4,` don't you need a coma between the two?

Comment: Always a good idea to check the result of `sscanf()` as in `int cnt = sscanf(temp,"%s %s...&temp6); if (cnt != 9) Oops();`.

Comment: When using `%s`, recommend using length limits as in `"%14s %12s %f %f %f %12s %f %f %f"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `temp` is defined as `char *temp[512]` then you it isn't a string and you can't pass it to `sscanf`. It should be defined as `char temp[512]`.

Comment: @user3637283 Then you should accept this answer, and you should respond to the comments above about the missing comma, presumably a typo. In the future, make sure you copy/paste directly from your code.